# Cannot upload an image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to update an image to my database, I defined as property model (bounded by database) the following:

```
public byte[] AvatarImage { get; set; }
```

then I created another property which store the value in the `ViewModel`:

```
public IFormFile AvatarImage { get; set; }
```

this steps are also described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in the doc.
Iside my form, I added the following html:

```
<div class="form-group text-center col-lg-12">                                                        
    <img src="@Model.AvatarImage" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar" />
   <h6>@Localizer["UploadNewAvatar"] ...</h6>                                        
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="avatarUrl" asp-for="@Model.AvatarImages" />
</div>
```

when I submit the form the property `AvatarImage` is even `null`. But I don't understand why happen this, because all the other form properties are valorized correctly

Comment: `AvatarImages` is not same as `AvatarImage`. Use `asp-for="@Model.AvatarImage"`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing the form enctype.

Make sure you have:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ... inputs
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input type="file">` element assignment below seems to be wrong, because it uses `@Model` directive which outputs value of `AvatarImages` property (and the property is not exist in viewmodel class):

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="avatarUrl" asp-for="@Model.AvatarImages" />
```

The correct way is just using the property name like example below, because `asp-for="PropertyName"` is equivalent to `model => model.PropertyName` in HTML helper (assumed you have `@model` directive set to a viewmodel class):

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" asp-for="AvatarImage" />
```

Also don't forget to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in `<form>` tag helper:

```
<form asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="ActionName" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- form contents here -->
</form>
```

Reference: [Tag Helpers in forms in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 0):

First add enctype="multipart/form-data" to form ;

Then,check your @model, two situations :

1.Use Model directly, since the image is a byte array type, you need to convert the file type to byte[] during the submission process.

2.Or you could use ViewModel, and change the parameter type to viewmodel in the method.